# show commit count without any duplication in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I fetched logs from git using `git log --all --numstat --pretty=format:'--%h--%ad--%aN' --no-merges > ../git.log` and saved to a git.log file. The purpose of this to read the logs and find out stuffs like commit count of each author, total lines of code written by each other, total lines added, delete, contributions by year, month, day and many more.

For now, I could read the data and formatted it in a csv. However, the problem is the duplication of commit hash(sha) but its equally important as well. In the file format you see

```
--568dc3532--Thu Jun 17 14:29:30 2021 -0400--Sebastian Markbåge
1   1   fixtures/blocks/src/index.js
2   2   fixtures/concurrent/time-slicing/src/index.js
1   1   fixtures/devtools/scheduling-profiler/app.js
1   1   fixtures/dom/src/__tests__/wrong-act-test.js
0   1   packages/react-dom/index.classic.fb.js
0   1   packages/react-dom/index.js
0   1   packages/react-dom/index.modern.fb.js

--43f4cc160--Thu Jun 17 13:56:18 2021 +0100--Dan Abramov
10  19  packages/react-reconciler/src/__tests__/ReactSuspense-test.internal.js

--d0f348dc1--Wed Jun 16 19:44:44 2021 -0400--Brian Vaughn
27  28  packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberCommitWork.new.js
27  28  packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberCommitWork.old.js
58  0   packages/react-reconciler/src/__tests__/ReactSuspense-test.internal.js
```

in the commit hash 568dc3532, there are changes in 7 different files and the insertion and deletion is also depicted on each file which is supremely important for my analysis. But, when I calculate commit count for all author with this statement

```
commit_data.Author.value_counts().head(10)
```

This is the output of it

```
Dan Abramov           14294
Paul O’Shannessy      12090
Brian Vaughn          11250
Travis CI              9423
Sebastian Markbåge     6711
Andrew Clark           6028
Sophie Alpert          4849
Dominic Gannaway       3101
Vjeux                  2606
Circle CI              1293
Name: Author, dtype: int64
```

I get the count of duplicated commit as well. This is how my csv looks like

[image]

So, my question is how can I show the count of commits by each author without any duplication.

Here is the csv

https://gist.github.com/SanskarSans/b7a756f1fe8ee71619950f633c87cd41

Comment: That screenshot doesn't look like the expected output of `.value_counts()` which you'd expect to return a `pd.Series` object. Can you provide a sample (not as a screenshot) of `commit_data` that we can look at?

Comment: The screenshot is not an output of value_counts. Its a csv file that is generated after some cleaning on the logs file. Based on that CSV, I am working on the analysis part.  I have updated my question with output and also put my csv in the gist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate how you've made that pandas Dataframe from the code you've provided. But say I have a dummy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'SHA':['1', '1', '1', '2', '2','3','4','4'],
                    'Author':['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Harry', 'Harry','Mary','Bob','Bob']})

   SHA  Author
0   1   Bob
1   1   Bob
2   1   Bob
3   2   Harry
4   2   Harry
5   3   Mary
6   4   Bob
7   4   Bob
```

I can get the number of commits made per author by doing:

```
df.groupby(['Author'])['SHA'].nunique()
```

This creates a [DataFrameGroupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object that we use [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) on the `SHA` column to get the number of counts of unique commits.

Comment: This worked for me. May be you should put for particular author case as well so that it will cover multiple cases. I followed your solution `commits = (commit_data[commit_data["Author"] == author]
  .groupby(by=["Author"])["SHA"].nunique())`. Thank you for your help!